What is the point of knowing symmetries, conservation quantities of a system?
I think this kind of question has been asked, but i couldn’t find it.
Well i have already know things like symmetries, conserved quantities and Noether’s theorem, as well as their role in particle physics.
But i still don't get the idea of this topic.
For example, an object moving in $x$ direction with a constant velocity. One may prove that the conserved quantity in the case is momentum $p_x$ in $x$ direction, and invariance under coordinate transformation in $x$ axis. I do not see that knowing the object has conserved momentum $p_x$ would give anything useful further, why would we have to do complicated mathematic for this?

Adding to the existent answer, symmetry considerations are especially important in constructing Lagrangians/actions. Since you mention particle physics: If you were to write down some Lagrangian which should describe e.g. fermionic matter and electromagnetism, how would you do so? Symmetry principles guide you in this regard. That you should follow these symmetry constraints is experimentally motivated.

In general, symmetries tell us that the physical properties/behavior of a system remains unchanged under certain groups of actions.

This reasoning can be used to eliminate/constrain the dependencies of physical quantities. For example, in electrostatics, which is essentially about solving Laplace's equation, the dependence of potential on certain coordinates can be eliminated based on symmetry alone. The most common cases are cylindrical and spherical symmetry, from which we can conclude that there is no dependence on angle.

Many theories of physics involve differential equations in the variable(s) of interest. Conserved quantities often take the form
$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots) = \text{constant}$$
or
$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots)_{\text{before}} =f(x_1,x_2,\ldots)_{\text{after}}$$
where $x_n$ are the dynamical variables. By turning differential equations into algebraic ones, this reduces the number of differential equations and therefore the computational complexity.

They also act as an important check on whether a set of proposed equations of motion for a system are sensible.


Of course, in your trivial example, it may not seem like it's saying anything more, but in more complicated systems it definitely does. It would be hard to imagine solving Newtonian mechanics problems without using conservation of energy/momentum at all.

Thank you, if you may, do you have any example or text that i could read further?

@KanokponArm You will learn about them in Lagragian/Hamiltonian formalism and field theory.

Symmetries yield via Noether’s theorem 1st integrals, so that some of the 2nd-order EL equations can be replaced by 1st-order ODEs, which are simpler to solve.

This is totally new to me, i will look into it, thanks.

If you are proposing to throw your problem into a computer, symmetries provide a way of checking the accuracy of your solution: if the theory predicts that energy is conserved, then you can use that as a metric for error. If you are using an exactly conservative integrator, there should be zero truncation error for the conserved quantities, so now you have a metric for round-off error.

What if you didn't know that energy was conserved? Or momentum? Or what if a particular system had some other, less intuitive conserved quantities? Or what if you assumed that the world works the same when things are right-handed as when they are left-handed and you did an experiment that showed that they aren't - what conservation laws would be impacted? You are right that a boring old particle under no applied forces going in one direction having its momentum conserved is pretty boring, but math gets hard: be thankful they're starting with toy problems.
By the way, for the same effort as a single particle in a single direction, one may prove that momentum is conserved in every direction in regions of space with consistent laws of physics.

Suppose you have an elastic collision of two masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ that move with velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively. Conservation of energy and momentum tell us, that $E=E^\prime$ and $p=p^\prime$, so the energy before the collision must be equal to the (total) energy after the collision and the (total) momentum before the collision is equal to the momentum after the collision. So
$E_1+E_2 = E^\prime_1 + E^\prime_2$
and
$p_1+p_2 = p^\prime_1 + p^\prime_2$
With this I am able to derive the speeds of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ after the collision:
$$v^\prime_1 = \frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}v_1 + \frac{2m_2}{m_1+m_2}v_2$$
$$v^\prime_2 = \frac{2m_1}{m_1+m_2}v_1 + \frac{m_2-m_1}{m_1+m_2}v_2$$
It would be impossible to calculate (or to guess) if momentum and energy weren't conserved.
